# While does it go through the while loop twice

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have trying parse a text file called FileName that looks like:

```
KD JD 6s 5s 3c // no rank (king high)
AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind
```

Now I wanna store them into a vector (everything before "//").

```
int FileParsing(vector<Card> & v, char * FileName) {
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(FileName);
    if (!ifs.is_open()){
        cout << "file cannot be opened." << endl;
    } else {        
        string line;                    
        while(getline(ifs, line)){
            istringstream iss (line); 
            bool condition = CountWords(line); //dont worry about this method   
            ReadCardDefinitionStrings (condition, line, v);
        }       
    }
    return 0;
}


void ReadCardDefinitionStrings (bool condition, string line, vector<Card> & v){
    istringstream iss (line);   
    string CardDefinitionStrings;   //e.g. 2C, 3h, 7s, Kh
    if (condition) {
            while(iss>>CardDefinitionStrings){  
            if (CardDefinitionStrings == "//"){ //stop reading after it sees "//"
                return;
            }
            Card c = TestCard(CardDefinitionStrings);
            v.push_back(c);     
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is: when it sees "//" after 3c, it goes back to

```
    while(getline(ifs, line)){
        istringstream iss (line); 
        bool condition = CountWords(line);  
        ReadCardDefinitionStrings (condition, line, v);
    }
```

But this time, line is empty (I wanted it to be: AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind), which means this loop runs one time without doing anything. And the next run, line would be equal to AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to put a lot of code up (card definitions and the like). And, from what I could tell, you had a couple of redundant definitions in some places.

However, I've implemented what you want (the ability to parse a text file called FileName that looks like):

```
KD JD 6s 5s 3c // no rank (king high)
AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind
```

Assuming the input filestream has been initialized with the Filename:

```
ifstream ifs(FileName);

if (!ifs.is_open()) {
    cout << "file cannot be opened." << endl;
}
else {
    string line;

    //getline reads up until the newline character
    //but you want the characters up to "//"
    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) {

        //line has been read, now get rid of the "//"
        string substr = line.substr(0,line.find("//"));

        //assign the substr to an input stringstream
        istringstream iss(substr);

        //this will hold your card
            //NOTE: Since I don't have your implementation of Card, I put it as a string instead for demonstration purposes
        string card;

        //keep reading until you've read all the cards in the substring (from line)
        while (iss >> card) {
            v.push_back(card);//store the card in the vector
            cout << card << endl;//now output it to verify that the cards were read properly
        }

        cout << endl;//this is just for spacing - so it'll help us distinguish cards from different lines (in the output)
    }
    ifs.close();
}
```

Output:

```
KD
JD
6s
5s
3c

AH
Ks
Js
AD
Ac
```

Which is what you want. ;)

Comment: Very brilliant way of using substr()! I just tested your code, it was not something I was looking for though. But it would be much easier for me to explain now. Speaking of your code, in the second while, after cout << 3c, what the program does is it go back to first while(std::getline(ifs, line)) {, but the difference between this time and the first time is: the first time after the getline(), line = KD JD 6s 5s 3c // no rank (king high), but this time, it is empty. after it goes through this while loop, the next getline() will have line = AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind.

Comment: I just don't get why, there is one time while the line would be empty. And I am hoping to get KD JD 6s 5s 3c // no rank (king high) in the first getline() and AH Ks Js AD Ac // three of a kind in the second getline()

Comment: Did you run it? I tried it and I get both instances of both lines (from what you posted) and all the output that I posted. And, this is the logic of it: read the line (up to the newline) in the first while(), then truncate it, initialize the truncated string to the input stringstream, then have the stream read until all information from the stringstream has been read.

Comment: I have tried it on both Windows and Linux machines and it works flawlessly. You said that the issue you are having is that you are only reading one line and not the second?